# How to bind suggestions with text box with first and last name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

IDE: C#.net, Winforms, .net 4.0

I want to bind a text box with suggestions, suggestions will come from a list, that list is having space separated words for example 'Little Jhon' now with the help of following code I have implemented suggestion functionality, but I want when user type anything suggestions should come from both words, currently it is coming from first word only.

Code:

```
private void BindTournamentNames()
    {

//On Load Code
       List<String> lstNames= new List<string>();
       lstNames.Add("Little John");
       lstNames.Add("Hello Yogesh");



        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        txtBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;

        source.AddRange(lstNames.ToArray());

        txtBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;

        txtBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txtBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

    }
```

Now when I am typing in textBox 'Little' it is giving me suggestion, but when I am typing John it is not giving me suggestion, please tell me how to do this.

Comment: I dont think this feature exists you will probably need to do this yourself

Comment: split the 'name' on the space, - which means you'll have two 'name's to add.

Comment: Then the problem will be it will show both suggestions in different lines (eg.'Little' in one line and 'John' in other), and I want it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Well existing autoComplete functionality only supports searching by prefix. I have the same requirement in one of my project. So what i had done is -

Added a `ListBox` just below the `TextBox` and set its default visibility to false. Then use the `OnTextChanged` event of the TextBox and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ListBox to display and select the items. like this -

Note: Assume your **BindTournamentNames()** method called in Form's constructor.

```
protected void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        listBox1.Visible = false;
        return;
    }

    foreach (String s in textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
    {
        if (s.Contains(textBox1.Text))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);
            listBox1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

protected void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    listBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

good luck...